# How to query fulltext search that contain double quotes and non - double quotes word

Tags: php, mysql

I know how to perform full text search inside `double quotes` + full-text search with words without `double quotes`. But the problem is, I want to perform search string that contain both `double quotes` and `words`, I have tried research for a while but could not found any answers that match my needs. I have below `rows` in my `table` with column name `title`:

```
id1 = "can tuyen nhan vien cap 3 ngoai ngu tot hang dep";

id2 = "tuyen nhan vien giao hang";
```

Now when I want to search with string like below:

```
$string = $_GET['q']  ( "nhan vien" giao hang )
```

So above string contains both `words` and `double quotes`. If I use `"nhan vien"` only, it returns both rows as expected. 
But when I perform search contain both conditions `"nhan vien" giao hang` it's still return both rows, so I want it should returns only `id2` that contains whole matched words.

Below is my query :

```
$query = SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST ('($string)'IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Appreciated any advises. Thank you very much in advanced!

Comment: I'm not sure but have you try to escape it?

Comment: @Chay22: I use prepared statements with this db class
https://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class

Comment: SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST ('("nhan vien" giao hang)' IN BOOLEAN MODE) is my query

Comment: Are other boolean mode operators working properly beside `"`?

Comment: Also I think you need to put variable `$string` as an array

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from table 
WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST ('nhan vien " giao hang' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
AND title LIKE '%nhan vien giao hang%';
```